# create Uninstaller with Installshield

Tags: installshield, uninstallation, installshield-2010

I have created an installer with installshield and it is work. but I don't uninstall it.
How I can create an uninstaller for my project?

Answer (score 1):

The uninstallation is created automatically, and you should be able to uninstall from windows control panel.

However, many apps need special handlers or code written in the installer to handle uninstallation. This is specific to your installer.

Comment: Provided that you color between the lines and don't make any mistakes when writing your install....   If you do anything wierd and custom out of process then it won't know how to automatically undo that for you.